# Nest REST API - unable to set structure to away

Tags: nest-api

I've been using the same code for a few months now, then suddenly it decides to stop working. I searched through SO and Google and couldn't find an answer.

When I try to set nest to away using curl, I get this response back:

{"error":"Device is unable to service this request at this time"}

If I use the exact same code and just change the away value to home, it works fine, only setting it to away gives that error. I can also get and set the temperatures of all the devices without any problems.

Comment: In case anyone else stubles upon this question after getting "Bad Request", I had to put double quotes around the values I was sending. So sending the string `away` didn't work for me, I had to send `"away"`

Answer (score 0):

This error response occurs when a device has been [rate limited](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits). Since setting home/away is at a structure level and affects all thermostats in your that structure.  If any one thermostat is rate limited you will be blocked as indicated.

Are you sure you are able to control the thermostat temperature for all thermostats in that structure during the time that you are receiving this error?

Comment: Well, I didn't try setting the temperature on all of them (I have three), but I never had a problem with setting the temperature at all. Also, I don't think I'm getting anywhere near the limit, I'm not making a lot of api calls at all. So I'm not really sure what it can be, but I think it's working now again (I didn't change anything)

Comment: Due to the effects on battery level, the limit for writing to thermostats, e.g. setting temperature or setting home/away state, is not very high. Only about 6 calls per hour, which under normal operation works fine, since most users are changing their thermostat settings that often.

Comment: I think that's exactly what the problem is. My thermostats also don't have a common wire, the battery gets low a lot on days that the heat doesn't stay on very long, this might be why the calls weren't going through.